# Interpreting /scan topic values using Hokuyo wrapper

Tags: lidar, scan, hokuyo, topic, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using Hokuyo UST 10LX Lidar. I have downloaded the wrapper and I am able to get scan data on /scan topic. But the values from lidar does not match with the actual distance between the obstacle and the lidar. Can I know how to map data coming out from wrapper on /scan topic to real distance ?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238198/interpreting-/scan-topic-values-using-hokuyo-wrapper/) by [asdfgf](https://answers.ros.org/users/26977/asdfgf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2016-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Supply voltage was less than the voltage range mentioned in the data sheet. Once I increased the voltage, I could get the correct distance.

---

Originally posted by [asdfgf](https://answers.ros.org/users/26977/asdfgf/) with karma: 42 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0